# Interactions and objectives saving freezes application

Tags: javascript, scorm

In my flash application I use pipwerks scorm wrapper to save different scorm values. Now, when I started saving interactions and objectives it takes considerable amount of time (5-6 seconds) to save. These arrays are not big (7 elements each), why does it take so long to save it? I have local LMS server, so network is not an issue here.

How can I impove it?

Edit: just added some logs and it appears that there is no "heavy" elements - all of them take same time to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Its not you, its them.

You are most likely falling victim to a poor implementation of the SCORM Runtime API.  What commonly happens is your sending get/set value commands via the content "wrapper" which communicates with the LMS Runtime API.  Instead of the LMS caching the student attempt it is making long round trips to the Server to return back data and set data.  This can equate to 1-12 seconds of actual lag which causes a hour glass or beach ball on a mac.  Its almost like a denial of service attack.

Objectives and Interactions require making several individual sets of data so that "spam" of messages trigger this latency.  Had the LMS used a cached attempt they only would of made a round trip to the server on a Commit call.   9 chances out of 10, this has been wrong for a long time on their system.  And would require a massive re-write to fix it.  I will abstain from listing out all the platforms I've experienced this on as many of them charge subscription fees and enterprise companies pay to use their services.  Unfortunately its just a bad design.  **Their system is making synchronous aka blocking calls to their server.  250ms DNS lag x 12 calls = bad user experience.**

I have physically been told "Don't make that many SCORM calls." and "Can you stop it from doing this".  I have physically taken down a LMS due to this too ;).  A large percentage of SCOs in the wild do not use objectives and interactions so many of these greater issues with latency go unchecked.

My Bookmarklet will highlight if you fall victim to this latency https://cybercussion.com/bookmarklets/SCORM.  Use that when viewing a SCO because it will make a series of status calls to the API and calculate the actual latency for you.  I've seen as much as 400ms per call!

The LMS implementation ultimately had 3 choices when designing their API.

- Cached: You load the Student Attempt and only send the data on a commit call.
- Cached Hybrid: You load the Student attempt and only send the changed data on commit.
- Non-Cached: You make server round trips setting and getting data. In a limited number of SCORM calls you will experience some latency.  The only pro I can pull out of the air on this implementation is the fact you may retain some small amount of data if the power goes out or the network goes down.  But the above options can call commit more periodically to address that to a degree too.

I'd smoke test on scorm.com.  Develop a repeatable process to take up support with the platform you are encountering this issue on.  Even though your edit states it's local, the blocking calls I highlighted above can contribute to this latency.

GL

Comment: Love your headline :)

Comment: Just want to add that I've seen a "normal" (read bad) cached version with a badly behaving server-side component, it had a non-standard implementation that would fall over and take 30+ seconds due to the server becoming unresponsive (specifically they decided that one of the fields could only accept whole numbers, and not floating points).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Mark's answer, I agree it sounds like the LMS is processing via synchronous xmlhttprequest (aka XHR or AJAX) instead of async. Learn more about sync vs async here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

When using synchronous XHR, the page will NOT process any JavaScript until the XHR request is completed. If the server is slow, this can take a few seconds. If you make repeated calls close to one another, they add up considerably. It can conceivably take a minute just to process a handful of activities over the span of a few pages. From the user's perspective, the course feels broken.

Agree with Mark that testing in SCORM Cloud is a great way to ensure your course is functioning properly and that the slowness is in your local LMS, not the course itself.

If you want to improve your local test environment, and are using a local LMS, look for xmlhttprequest or AJAX in the LMS's JavaScript codebase and see of you can set to async.